# Does Carmilla have co-conspirators?

Tags: vampire, carmilla

In Le Fanu's *Carmilla*, a ruse is used twice to place Carmilla with a family who clothe and feed her for an extended period, almost like a cuckoo. But who are the "parents" who drop her off with these families? All kinds of mystery surrounds them, and it is clear that these "parents" are hard to contact. What motive could anyone have to help Carmilla in this way? Are they also vampires? Or does Carmilla have some other undisclosed powers that made this possible?

Comment: As far as I remember from the novel, only a "mother" appears, not two parents. In both cases it is never clarified who this mother is, other than she is in a mission of great urgency and who never again appears. Perhaps a thrall?

Comment: Carmilla is dropped off with two different families at different times (one time is recounted as a story within the story). It may be the same "parent" in both cases but I can't tell. A thrall sounds sort of plausible but that would imply a power that isn't explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are suggestions in [Sheridan Le Fanu's story](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/10007/10007-h/10007-h.htm), but nothing more, that her "mother" is also one of the undead.  They are more atmospheric than definitive, but they seem to be about all that there is to go on.

The first direct suggestion comes in the first sentence of chapter III, just after the mother has insinuated Carmilla into her new host household and is departing in her carriage.

> We followed the *cortege* with our eyes until it was swiftly lost to sight in the misty wood; and the very sound of the hoofs and the wheels died away in the silent night air.

Le Fanu italicizes "cortege" here which suggests either that he considered it not a naturalized English word, or that he wants to emphasize it (or that he wants the reader to be unsure why it is italicized; he does not italicize the less English word *schloss*, for example).  The word *cortege* is not entirely out of place where the author uses it, but it is certainly a bit odd, since the main use of *cortege* in English is to describe the vehicles in a funeral procession.  This seems to be a sly insinuation that the "mother" occupying the carriage is not normally alive.

However, shortly before that, there are suggestions that the "mother" is fully aware of what she is doing in placing the monster in a new nest of victims—that she is not under some kind of mind control.

> I cannot do that, sir, it would be to task your kindness and chivalry too cruelly,” said the lady, distractedly.
> ...
> The lady threw on her daughter a glance which I fancied was not quite so affectionate as one might have anticipated from the beginning of the scene....

There is also this later exchange (in chapter XI), in which the "mother" claims to be old, in spite of her interlocutor's doubts:

> “‘I should take chance for that,’ I answered. ‘It is vain trying to make yourself out an old woman; your figure betrays you.’
>
> “‘Years, nevertheless, have passed since I saw you, rather since you saw me, for that is what I am considering.  Millarca, there, is my daughter; I cannot then be young, even in the opinion of people whom time has taught to be indulgent, and I may not like to be compared with what you remember me.

Again, none of these is definitive, but taken together, there is a real sense of suggestion that the vampire girl's mother is also ancient and undead.

Comment: Nice observations! I also mentally flagged the word cortège but I wasn't sure if maybe the meaning had drifted over the centuries. I also wonder if anything "Millarca"'s mother says is true or, like with Carmilla, it's pretty much all lies.